# Change text on click JavaScript [Close]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript so I need little help about.
I have function

```
var encodedString = Base64.encode(string);
```

and

```
var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
```

so in div I am printing encodedString

```
<h2 id="names"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(encodedString)</script></h2>
```

how to make it when i click on button i want to change the text in decodedString that is getting from url parameter.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: btn.click=function(){document.getElementById("names").innerHTML = Base64.decode(encodedString);};

Comment: default string is "encodedString" when i click on the button i want to change the string to decodedString @WhoAmI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my sample code,replace with your DIV id, Not sure its that you need.

```
 <script>
        function Print(){
          document.getElementById('yourDivId').innerHTML = Base64.decode(encodedString);
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="Print()">Print</button>
    <div id="yourDivId"></div>
```